# Forcing Deep Freeze to Thawed by registry

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry, deep-freeze

SO, after messing up with windows updates and deep freeze, I got to a state where the windows won't start because of the update's last configuration stepts and it reboots its self.

Does any one know how to set by registry, to force deep freeze to Thawed instead of Deep Freeze mode?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the system clock ahead 60 days in the bios.

Comment: yea, that problem was a few months ago so finally I've formated the computer... but I remember trying this idea to, but with no effect